# Pipeline Utility Steps - zip empty folders

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to zip the sources of a project using Jenkn's [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#pipeline-utility-steps) `zip` command.
It zips everything except for some empty folders (e.g. some "META-INF").
Is there a way to make it bundle everything?
I have also tried via `tar` with the same results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows 10 [doesn't do it by default](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/empty-folders-no-longer-included-in-zip-file-in/55b7f0c6-1664-42a0-822c-2c8d961775da).

Using 7-zip solved it. If someone uses this solution, don't forget to archive the generated files later if you need to do something else with them, like copying to another workspace.

```
bat "${ZIP_HOME}7z a myZipFile.zip srcFolder"
```

and in the post section:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.zip', fingerprint: true
```